# Retrieving data from ps_cart table in prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I am hoping someone has  experience with retrieving data from ps_cart table in prestashop

How to retrieve data from ps_cart table in prestashop using cart_id. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the cart class for that.

```
$cart = new Cart($id_cart);
```

now you will have the cart derails in cart variables.

just print it to see

```
print_r($cart);
```